# How to ignore compiler warnings for macros defined in third-party headers?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

Currently it's possible to tell the compiler to ignore warnings from a given header by considering it a "system header", including the header via `-isystem /path/to/dir`.

However, this still won't work if the warning stems from a **macro** defined in such a header. Is there any way to ignore warnings also for macros? I'm mostly interested in GCC and Clang solutions.

Examples below are based on Clang 14.0.0 and GCC 11.1.0 on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
// include/third_party.h
#pragma once

#define MY_CAST(x) ((int)x)
```

```
// main.cpp
#include <third_party.h>

int main() 
{
    int x = MY_CAST(123);
    return x;
}
```

With GCC:

```
$ g++ -isystem include -Wold-style-cast main.cpp 
In file included from main.cpp:1:
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:5:21: warning: use of old-style cast to ‘int’ [-Wold-style-cast]
    5 |     int x = MY_CAST(123);
      |                     ^~~
```

With Clang:

```
$ clang++ -isystem include -Wold-style-cast main.cpp
$
```

Example that works with GCC but not with Clang:

```
// include/third_party2.h
#pragma once

struct Foo
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

#define FOO Foo{.x = 123, .y = 321}
```

```
// main.cpp
#include <third_party2.h>

int main() 
{
    Foo f = FOO;
    return f.x;
}
```

```
$ g++ -isystem include -pedantic main2.cpp
$
```

```
$ clang++ -isystem include -pedantic main2.cpp 
main2.cpp:5:13: warning: designated initializers are a C++20 extension [-Wc++20-designator]
    Foo f = FOO;
            ^
include/third_party2.h:9:17: note: expanded from macro 'FOO'
#define FOO Foo{.x = 123, .y = 321}
                ^
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: How about not using the macro, but define your own access `const auto rcc = static_cast<RCC_Typedef*>(RCC_BASE);`

Comment: Yes, I'd normally do that, but it's tedious and error-prone in this case. I'm using many other registers and I don't want to define then by hand (it's the definitions of registers for an STM32 microcontroller). I'm just surprised they thought about "system headers" but left macros out of it...

Comment: What are you using to build? Usually this stuff can be suppressed as part of the build system.

Comment: @Taekahn just regular GCC or clang. As I wrote, I'm already aware of -isystem, but that doesn't work for macros.

Comment: Your 1st example (`main.cpp`) doesn't trigger the warning with GCC 11.  I don't have a GCC 9 available, so I can't test.  I'm surprised that you see a warning.  Anyway, I recommend using a newer GCC.

Comment: However, I could reproduce your problem with `-pedantic` and only with `clang++-13`, the same as you.  I think that may be a bug in Clang.

Comment: @alx I still get the warning on GCC 11...

# g++-11 -isystem include -Wold-style-cast main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:1:
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:5:21: warning: use of old-style cast to 'int' [-Wold-style-cast]
    5 |     int x = MY_CAST(123);
      |                     ^~~

# g++-11 --version
g++-11 (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 11.1.0

Comment: Huh!  My fault!!  Or, actually, GCC's fault!!!  See what caused the silencing:  I rewrote your code, instead of just copy-pasting.  I wrote the macro argument inside parentheses, as I'm used to do, and I didn't notice that you wrote it without them.  Guess what? GCC warns about old-style casts only if you don't use them.  That's definitely a bug in GCC.  Try: `#define MY_CAST(x) ((int)(x))` :)

Comment: I read the email you sent to Clang reporting the bug.  Did you also report it to GCC?  If so, could you please share some links here, to follow the bugs?  Thanks.

Comment: Damn, that was really tricky, great finding! Sure, I'll update the bug, or perhaps simply answer the question now that I get a better understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be simply a bug in GCC/Clang. In general, warnings *are* expected to be ignored when coming from system macros, and most of them are ignored. I just happen to have come across very concrete use cases where the warning is not ignored.

In case someone is interested in the GCC issue, here's the bug report:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103862

For Clang, I've asked a general question here:
https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2021-December/069648.html

And reported issue here:
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/52944

Bonus: for clang-tidy, I have a patch to make sure warnings from macros are ignored:
https://reviews.llvm.org/D116378

Thanks everyone for contributing to this investigation!

Answer (score 1):

Not what you asked for, but should be better than using pragmas directly.

```
#define ALLOW_OLD_CAST(...) \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push") \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wold-style-cast\"") \
    __VA_ARGS__ \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")
```

And then `ALLOW_OLD_CAST( RCC->CR1 |= 0x0001; )`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It's indeed much better to isolate the suppression into a single macro. I'm still a bit unhappy in terms of readability given that I'll need to use this pattern quite frequently in the code.

Comment: It should be trivial to `#define NEWRCC` and use it in place of `RCC`.