# How can I limit where clang code analyser in QtCreator looks?

Tags: c++, clang, qt-creator, compiler-warnings

I get warnings when using macros from third party library headers. To clarify, I'm talking about warnings shown in the source code editor, not when actually building the code like is the case for [How to ignore compiler warnings for macros defined in third-party headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70488470/how-to-ignore-compiler-warnings-for-macros-defined-in-third-party-headers). For instance, when I use GLOG via Torch (`LOG(n)` in Torch's `c10/util/logging_is_not_google_glog.h`), I get warnings about 1) using old-style casts and 2) dropping `const` in the cast.

Now I would like to keep those warnings for everywhere else (inside my own code), but disable them for thirdparty code. Most answers on the internet focus on disabling a particular type of warning, but what I'm after is a particular *source* of warnings.

Is there a way to configure clang for QtCreator to ignore warnings in macros from particular folders, or the opposite, to only show them if they come from code in particular folders?

MWE:
[image: MWE]

Clarification: I am *not* using clang to build the code, so there is not build setup where I could set any clang flags.

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70488470/how-to-ignore-compiler-warnings-for-macros-defined-in-third-party-headers?noredirect=1&lq=1
If you specify the `torch` folder as a system header folder (`-isystem`), then the warnings should not be displayed.

Comment: Eerrrmm... that is the link I've posted in the first paragraph saying that it is *not* what I'm after...

Comment: Then I'm sorry but `Is there a way to configure clang [..] to ignore warnings in macros from particular folders?` Is your question, and the approach specified there (`-isystem`) is the answer. The warnings shown inside the editor are also generated by running the compiler.

Comment: Well, I cannot replace `-I` with `-isystem` when I don't have any `-I`. `The warnings ... are also generated by running the compiler.` - running the compiler how, where, on what code, with which flags? I haven't found any settings for it, that is my problem... I have a cmake-based setup I launch via a custom build shell script.

Comment: If you are using cmake, then the way to get cmake to call clang with `-isystem`  is 
`target_include_directory(your_cmake_target SYSTEM PRIVATE your_directory)` (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html).
You could add your 'torch' directory there and then `#include <script.h>`, or add a parent directory to make the includes more idiomatic.